# Definition for "UK gold"

Tags: meaning

I am a poor colonial, Canadian, watching the BBC legal series "Silk". Here is the exchange for which I need a definition:

Billy: "... you're gold."
Aisha: "No,...perhaps UK gold."

What is the meaning of 'UK gold' ?

Answer (score 7):

UK Gold is a TV channel here in the UK that specialises in reruns of old television series.

Comment: I'd like to think that such an anodyne meaning does not tarnish the UK gold that is still being mined in miniscule amounts somewhere in Wales.